# Incrementing a variable to 100 then deincrementing to 0 and back again in a loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, increment

I'm just wondering what the most "pythonic" way to increment a varible `x` all the way from 0 to 100, then when `x` reaches 100, deincrement back to 0 then back again to 100 in a loop over and over...

Something like this:

```
x = 0
while True:
  if x < 100:
    x += 1
  elif x == 100:
    x -= 1
```

NB: Above code is broken, hence my question. :)

What is the simplest way to do this - not necessarily the shortest code, not looking for a one liner, just a really nice bit of code.

Comment: This doesn't do what you want it to do. `elif x == 100:` will decrement it back to 99, at which point `if x < 100:` is `True`, so it increments again. It's more important to make sure something works before trying to optimise.

Comment: Yeah I realise the code above doesnt work.

Comment: Well your original question didn't state that. Good luck finding any clarification in what's "pythonic" in what's been offered up as answers. I would have rated functionality above pythonicism (is that a word?) but there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying this?

```
x = 0
inc = 1
while True:
  # do your job here
  if x == 0:
    inc = 1
  elif x == 100:
    inc = -1
  x += inc
```

Comment: Actually, I like this method the best, so I have changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I find one-liners simple... so what about this:

*Python 2*:

```
from itertools import *
ups_and_downs = cycle(chain(xrange(100), xrange(100, 0, -1)))
```

*Python 3*:

```
from itertools import *
ups_and_downs = cycle(chain(range(100), range(100, 0, -1)))
```

(edited to remove the one-off error)

Comment: Note that your ranges aren't symmetrical.

Comment: You are right. And as a result, the iteration turned back too early. Chaining and cycling `[0, 100)` and `[100, 0)` should work better and look better too ;)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: they should not be symmetrical I think since otherwise `100` and `0` would be printed twice.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your code **does not work**: it will count to 100, and then swap between 99 and 100. So: 1,2,3,..,99,100,99,100,99,...

Actually the most Pythonic way is probably **not** to increment/decrement at all, but use two `range`s:

```
while True:
    for x in range(101):
        pass
        #do something with x
    for x in range(99,0,-1):
        pass
        #do something with x
```

Or construct an infinite generator with [itertools](/questions/tagged/itertools):

```
generator = itertools.cycle(itertools.chain(range(101),range(99,0,-1)))
```

and then you can use it as:

```
for x in generator:
    pass
    #do something with x
```

Fr instance (I here use `2` because it makes the answer more compact):

```
for x in itertools.cycle(itertools.chain(range(3),range(1,0,-1))):
    print(x)
```

will produce:

```
0
1
2
1
0
1
2
1
0
```

the loop will be repeated infinitely.

A way to fix your code however would be to add a direction, but this is probably **not** very *Pythonic*:

```
x = 0
dr = True
while True:
    if dr:
        x += 1
        if x >= 100:
            dr = False
    else:
        x -= 1
        if x <= 0:
            dr = True
    #do something with x
```

Comment: Good call on the use of two ranges - much more Pythonic.

Comment: Thank you - yeah, I like the two ranges.  I accepted this answer as it has a good explanation for multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using two loops!

```
while True:
    for x in range(100):
        do_something(x)
    for x in range(98, 0, -1):
        do_something(x)
```

Or you could use a variable to keep track of which direction you're going:

```
delta = 1
x = 0
while True:
    do_something(x)
    x += delta
    if x < 1 or x > 99:
        delta = -delta
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your current solution won't exactly work - you'll deincrement back to 99, then cycle between 99 and 100.

The simplest might be to add a `direction` flag, for example:

```
x = 0
isIncreasing = True
while True:
  if isIncreasing = True:
    x += 1
    if x == 100:
      isIncreasing = False
  else: 
    x -= 1
    if x == 0:
      isIncreasing = True
```

I'm there's a more "one line" way to do this with itertools (see above posts), but this would be the most "direct" solution in your current case. Of course, what you're really looking for is a `generator`.

Answer (score 0):

well since no one else is doing it, why not some generator fun!

```
def lazy_forever_and_ever(hi, lo, start=0, step=1):
    x = start
    vals = {hi: lo, lo: hi}
    target=lo
    while True:
        if x == target:
            target = vals[target]
        if x >= target:
            yield x
            x -= step
        elif x <= target:
            yield x
            x += step

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _4eva = lazy_forever_and_ever(0, 10, 0, 1)
    print([next(_4eva) for _ in range(20)])

# output
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```